# Count number of duplicates in other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, count, duplicates

I have two data.frames `dfA` and `dfB`. Both of them have a column called `key`.
Now I'd like to know how many duplicates for A$key there are in B$key.

```
A <- data.frame(key=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
B <- data.frame(key=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "D"))
```

It should be A=2, B=3, C=0 and D=1. Whats the most easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A <- data.frame(key=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
B <- data.frame(key=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "D"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

B %>%
  filter(key %in% A$key) %>%                 # keep values that appear in A
  count(key) %>%                             # count values
  complete(key = A$key, fill = list(n = 0))  # add any values from A that don't appear

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   key       n
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A         2
# 2 B         3
# 3 C         0
# 4 D         1
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `table`

```
table(factor(B$key, levels = sort(unique(A$key))))
#A B C D 
#2 3 0 1
```

`factor` is needed here such that we also 'count' entries that do not appear in `B$key`, that is `C`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` you can do:

```
A %>%
 left_join(B %>% #Merging df A with df B for which the count in "key" was calculated
            group_by(key) %>%
            tally(), by = c("key" = "key")) %>%
 mutate(n = ifelse(is.na(n), 0, n)) #Replacing NA with 0

  key n
1   A 2
2   B 3
3   C 0
4   D 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you mean how many occurrences of each value of `A$key` you have in `B$key`?

You can obtain this by coding `B$key` as factor with the unique values of `A$key` as levels.

```
o <- table(factor(B$key, levels=unique(A$key)))
```

*Yielding:*

```
> o

A B C D 
2 3 0 1
```

If you really want to count duplicates, do

```
dupes <- ifelse(o - 1 < 0, 0, o - 1)
```

*Yielding:*

```
> dupes

A B C D 
1 2 0 0
```